# Android studio 3.0 : error occur while compiling app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, butterknife, android-studio-3.0

Got error while compiling android application.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'
The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
- butterknife-5.1.2.jar (butterknife-5.1.2.jar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use 5.1.2 jar.Instead use this latest version in the gradle and also use the annotation to make it work.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the latest version of this lib. And don't forget to add annotationProcessor in your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below line in your app gradle

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
 annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

and after then using BindView instead of Bind in your class.